# Lebesgue Integral Definition. Integrating a characteristic of a set of infinite measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm reading the book *Real Analysis* from Elias.M.Stein and Rami Shakarchi.

In the chapter about abstract integration, when the book starts to construct the integral, it limits itself to $\sigma$-finite spaces. I've been told that I can define the integral in general space without any problem but I am struggling to get a result that is obvious if one has a $\sigma$-finite space, maybe here is not true.

This book starts defining the integral for simple functions, meaning lineal combinations of characteristic of measurable sets **of finite measure**, putting $$\int \sum_{1}^nc_i\chi_{E_i} \ d\mu = \sum_1^nc_i\mu(E_i)$$

After that it basically define the integral of a positive function as $$\int f \ d\mu  = sup\{\int g, \ 0\leq g\leq f\}$$ with $g$ simple. At this point one can observe that the first step in the definition, i.e, the definition for simple functions does not tell someone the value of $$\int \chi_E \ d\mu$$ when $\mu(E) = \infty$. However, once one has the second defintion, if the space is $\sigma$-finite, the next reasoning proves that the integral above has the value $\infty$ as one may expect; As the space is $\sigma$-finite, $X = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$ with $E_i$ of finite measure, then $E = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}(E\cap E_i)$. Let me call $B_n = \cup_{i=1}^{n}(E\cap E_i)$. Now by the second definition, or by monotony, $$\int \chi_E \ d\mu \geq \int \chi_{B_n} \ d\mu = \mu(B_n)$$ where the last equal follows from definition for simple functions, as $B_n$ has finite measure. To finish if one takes $n \to \infty$, by the continuity of the measure one has $\mu(B_n) \to \mu(E) = \infty$ and then $$\int \chi_E \ d\mu = \infty$$

This seems really clear but I am getting confused to get the same result if one doesn't have a $\sigma$-finite spaces. It is clear that I can't use the same reasoning.

One important observation is that I have seen books where admit sets of infinite measure in the first definition of integral, but this is not the case in this book. (Maybe because they restrict to $\sigma$-finite spaces).

Comment: Well, now I am convinced that this is not true. Not with the definition of the step 2. I think the answer given in this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665552/definition-of-the-lebesgue-integral-in-terms-of-simple-functions-with-finite-mea?rq=1) is a counterexample.

Comment: You don't read my description, in fact it depends on how you define the integral on a space that are not $\sigma$-finite. The link above gives an example that if you define the integral as I do in the second definition then that equation does not hold. Take a look