# Choice of simple functions to define the general Lebesgue Integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

On a measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, the usual way to build a general Lebesgue Integral is to use the set of simple functions define as finite sum of linear combinations of characteristic functions of measurable sets (i.e. elements of $\Sigma$) and then use the non-negative ones to define the integral functional on them, and then use them to approximate from below the measurable positive functions to get their Lebesgue Integral.

I was wondering what happens if we just use the simple functions define as finite sum of linear combinations of characteristic functions of measurable sets with *finite* measure. The set of such simple functions has the nice properties of being a Riesz space, verifying the Stone axiom, and allowing a natural definition on it of the Integral as a linear functional, on the contrary to the previous set.

I am aware that if we do not suppose the measure $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite, we do not get all the integrable measurable functions (see this question [Definition of the Lebesgue integral in terms of simple functions with finite measure support](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665552/14860)) but do we get the usual space $L^1(X,\mu)$ of functions with finite integral of their absolute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because for $f\in L^1$, we can approximate the positive part from below only by simple functions that have a smaller and hence also finite integral. Hence, these simple functions must have finite support, so explicitly requiring them to have finite support does not matter.

Comment: Thank you. That was just under my nose and I could not see it during one day!